# Why does Java method return null?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, bluej

I am trying to debug why my Java method returns null. Here are the details.

We are making a simple card "game" and Im having trouble with external method call and creating a new object.. It is a deck of cards ..So 1 class for the cards, 1 class for deck and 1 for the Game

This is my class the code goes into

```
 public class Game
 {
  private InputReader reader;
  private Deck deck;
  private ArrayList<Card> listCard;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Game
 */
public Game()
{
    deck = new Deck();
    reader = new InputReader()
    listCard = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

/**
 *
 */
public void dealCard()
{
   listCard.add(deck.takeCard());
}

}// End of Game class
```

and this is the deck class which I will grabbing methods from

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 /**
  * Write a description of class Deck here.
  * 
  * @author  
  * @version 2012.05.31
  */
 public class Deck
{
private ArrayList<Card> redblue;

/**
 * Main constructor for objects of class Deck
 */
public Deck()
{
    redblue = new ArrayList<Card>();
}


   public Card takeCard()
{
      **return redblue.remove(0);**  /// this is the Index.pointer.exception
}



}
}// End of class
```

So my problem is im trying to pull the first card off the deck and add it to my "hand" ..So im trying to call dealCard() which calls takeCard()..The takeCard() works fine but when I try and call if through dealCard() it returns null and errors out because i cant add null to arrayList..
I think my problem might be external method calling not step up with the right variables, I dunno

Thanks in advance

***Edited. Removed irrelevant methods and Class..

Comment: If you're seeing a NPE (NullPointerException) you'll need to indicate which line of code is causing it.

Comment: @SmilesNLulz please change the link in your profile page..that sort of thing will get in trouble on this site

Comment: [We can't inspect your entire code base;](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/175248) could you provide us with the specific snippet where you're getting the `NullPointerException`, and corresponding usage?

Comment: Can you narrow this done to a smaller test case program?

Comment: There is a missing semicolon in your Game class
    reader = new InputReader()

Comment: OP - Yes sorry its just the instance fields of Game class, dealCard() of Game class and takeCard of Deck Class. Am in process of editing and semicolon glitch was not issue (accidental backspace)..And getting NPE at takeCard() from deck when i call dealCard()

Comment: I see the `dealCard()` method, but I don't see anywhere in the code above where you call the method!

Comment: Oh my goodness. Why so many *setters*? Please strive for *controlled mutability* :(

Comment: @pst: "controlled mutability"? Do you have a link on this?

Comment: @SmilesNLulz The only reason that a `NullPointerException` would be thrown at the line you pointed out is if `redblue` was `null`. From the code snippet you provided though, `redblue` cannot be `null`, since it is created at `Deck`'s construction. Is `takeCard` throwing an `NPE`, or is `takeCard` returning `null`? Is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown? In the code you removed on an edit, I never actually saw a call to `Deck.addCard`. I believe adding your calls to `addCard` to the question above will help us help you.

Comment: @pst: "Please strive for controlled mutability"? What does it have to do with the topic? Random evangelism and general preaching is rarely a good answer to anyone's question. Striving for immutability is only one of many available styles of coding - and it is particularly hard to force it on anyone.

Comment: Yes it is IndexOutOfBoundsException not NPE. I can add the card into the Deck class no problem using addCard() and then remove and return using takeCard() but the bug is coming when I call dealCard in the Game class. when i call dealCard() Its not adding to my ArrayList because it is returning null. If i display it before it gets added it comes back null..So dealCard() is not retrieving the return value from takeCard()..

Comment: `Deck.takeCard` will throw an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) if there is nothing in `redblue`. `Deck.takeCard` will return `null` if `null` was added to `redblue`. Make sure that when you call `Deck.addCard` you are not actually calling `Deck.addCard(null)`; it should be something like `Deck.addCard(new Card())`.

Comment: Im 99% sure its not the deck.addCard().. I feel like it has something to do with the instance variables and constructor in Game class and that I've made a small error in the way I intialized it..? Im using BlueJ so I can test my Card class and each class seperatly so I know its not addCard()

Comment: In your `Game` class, make sure to call `deck.addCard` before ever making a call to `deck.takeCard`. For testing purposes, you can call `deck.addCard` in `Game`'s constructor or even in the `Game`'s `play` method.

Comment: What I want to do is take a card from the redblue ArrayList<> and put it in my listCard Arraylist...

Comment: It's an IndexOutOfBoundsException? Why didn't you say that in your original post??? Cripes. -1.

Comment: I got mixed up. Rather new terms to me

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "comment". But it means what it sounds like: mutability is part of imperative programming/Java. But don't let it get out of hand (e.g. with a setter for every aspect of an object which should for all intents and purposes be [largely] immutable.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your constructor for Deck:

```
public Deck()
{
    redblue = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
```

After that constructor has run, how many cards are there in the redBlue ArrayList?

What do you think might happen if you try to remove a card from that ArrayList?

Comment: See I figured it had something to do with the constructors but i cant wrap my brain around it could you explain a bit further?

Comment: Do a small experiment.  Create a `new` ArrayList<Integer> and see how many integers are in your new ArrayList.  An ArrayList is a container.  Until you put something in it, it is an empty container.  Trying to remove something from an empty container can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to post some more code from your main(game class) showing us the usage of your deck and card classes. Only thing that took my attention now is this:

```
public Card takeCard()
{
      **return redblue.remove(0);**  /// this is the Index.pointer.exception
}
```

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) an exception can be thrown if:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).
```

Are you sure your deck is filled with cards? You could add a check to your method. If your list of cards is empty, 0 = it's size.

```
public void dealCard()
{
   Card card = deal.takeCard();

   if (card != null)
      listCard.add(deck.takeCard());
}

public Card takeCard()
{
    if ( !this.redblue.isEmpty() )
        return redblue.remove(0);

    return null;        
}
```

Comment: Hmm still no.. when I do takeCard() it returns a Card but when I call it from dealCard() it comes back with IndexOutOf.... Am intializing it correctly? Because it seems like i am not accessing the redblue ArrayList from dealCard but some new ArrayList

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for us to tell you whats wrong if you don't post more code showing your using of these classes. Edit your question and I will edit my answer if I find something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the first element of your

```
redblue
```

is null. Nulls are allowed in an ArrayList.

My guess is that there is more code where you fill in the Deck of cards and the first time around you are adding `null` to the `ArrayList`

Check the [`ArrayList` specification here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like redblue doesn't actually have anything in it! when you intialise it like so:

```
redblue = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

You're just creating an empty container for Cards, not actually putting cards in it.
What you may want to do is create a function to generate the cards for redblue.. something like..

```
public ArrayList<Card> createInitialDeck(){ 
  //Create an empty ArrayList
  //Do some code here to create new cards..
       //you might want to consider nested for loops if you're creating 13 cards of 4 different suits for example
       //while inside those for loop add each new card object to your array list

   //return arrayList;
}
```

then instead of `redblue = new ArrayList<Card>();` you'd do `redblue = createInitialDeck();`.